# Mongo find an array inside a collection and get only that data

Tags: json, node.js, database, mongodb

How can I get only the data from menus which _id is 1?

I've tried:

```
db.collection("restaurants")
  .find({ name : String(name), "menus._id": Number(id)} )
  .toArray(function (err, result) {
```

But I still get the full result from restaurant and not only the menu

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use projection to retrieve only the menus field.

```
db.collection("restaurants").find( { name: String(name), "menus._id": Number(id) }, { _id: 0, menus: 1 } ).toArray( function(err,result) { } );
```

with or without projection the `_id` field is returned by default, you have to turn it off by setting the `_id` field to 0. 0 means don't show the value of this field, while 1 does the opposite